# "mit schuld sein" korrekt?

Tags: particle

Kann "mit" als eine Art Partikel zusammen mit "sein" genutzt werden?

Wir kennen "mit" von "mit ansehen" und "mitmachen" als je nach Verb-Bedeutung trennbaren oder untrennbaren Teil des Verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im Anschluss an die Diskussion in den Kommentaren (isb. von Benutzer *tofro*) hier eine überarbeitete Antwort. Laut dem Handbuch von Fleischer & Barz (Wortbildung der deutschen Gegenwartssprache, De Gruyter (4)2012, S. 424) kann man unterscheiden zwischen einer (adverbiellen) Verbpartikel "mit" und einem eigenständigen Adverb "mit". Wenn das Prädikat nach dem "mit" auch noch eine Betonung erhält, sei es keine Partikel, sondern ein Adverb. Das ist hier wahrscheinlich so: "dass er MIT SCHULD ist" (im Unterschied zur einzelnen Betonung bei "MITschuldig ist", anderes Wort).

Im übrigen ist der Unterschied aber äußerst fein, auch die Bedeutung sehr ähnlich. Ob ein Verb zwei Partikeln haben kann, darüber besteht bei den Grammatikern Uneinigkeit.

Comment: "Mit" ist in diesem Beispiel in strengem Sinn keine Partikel, sondern ein Adverb - es kann nicht ohne Sinnveränderung weggelassen werden.

Comment: Interessant. Wie unterscheidest du das? Weil der Bedeutungsbeitrag regelmäßig ist? Wir haben in anderen Fällen als hier allerdings Zusammenschreibung...

Comment: Das 'mit' kann außerdem, wie im Beispiel, mit einem bestehenden Verbpartikel gemeinsam auftreten, was normale Verbpartikel nicht könnten.

Comment: @alazon genauso wie geschrieben. Meine Auffassung einer Haupteigenschaft einer Partikel im Deutschen ist der nicht vorhandene Einfluss auf den ausgedrückten Sachverhalt, sondern nur eine "Abtönung". Das ist bei "mit" nicht gegeben.

Comment: Habe daraufhin überarbeitet, siehe nun neue Version oben. -- Allerdings müssen "Modalpartikeln" und "Verbpartikeln" auseinandergehalten werden, die werden zu Unrecht mit demselben Ausdruck bezeichnet.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde das nicht am Verb festmachen, sondern eher am Attribut, das Bestandteil des Prädikats ist:

> Die Ehefrau des Angeklagten ist mitschuldig (oder mit schuldig).

> Die Klimaerwärmung ist mit ein Grund für besondere Wetterphänomene

> Das ist mit das wichtigste aller Bücher über Computerprogrammierung

Als *Partikel* sähe ich "mit" an dieser Stelle aber sehr ungern - Eine wesentliche Eigenschaft von Partikeln im Deutschen ist, dass sie ohne Sinnveränderung weggelassen können. Das ist hier aber nicht der Fall, "mit" trägt einen wesentlichen Bedeutungsanteil. Daher wird es von den meisten Wörterbüchern als **Adverb** kategorisiert.